# Migration:load list of migrations everytime I try to run migration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orocommerce, doctrine-migrations

I just started orocommerce. I was creating a migration to add a field to the customer table. But whenever I try to dry run the migration I get a long list of migrations to run alongside the migration I created. And even after running the oro:migration:load many times these still show up.

List of migrations:

> Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\LoadEntityConfigStateMigration
> Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\UpdateBundleVersionMigration
> Oro\Bundle\CheckoutBundle\Migrations\Schema\RemoveWorkflowFieldsMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\RefreshExtendCacheMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migration\UpdateEntityConfigMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntitySerializedFieldsBundle\Migration\SerializedDataMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\UpdateExtendConfigMigration
> Oro\Bundle\ActivityContactBundle\Migration\ActivityContactMigration
> Oro\Bundle\ActivityListBundle\Migration\ActivityListMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\UpdateExtendIndicesMigration
> Oro\Bundle\OrganizationProBundle\Migrations\Schema\UpdateConfigsWithOrganizationMigration
> Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migration\WarmUpEntityConfigCacheMigration
> Oro\Bundle\ScopeBundle\Migration\Schema\UpdateScopeRowHashColumn

how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These migrations run every time intentionally to warm up some caches and do additional changes that may be needed before and after schema changes. You don’t need to fix anything here.